# How do I update multiple columns in MySQL (Through Java)?

Tags: java, mysql, syntax

So this is just a snippet of my code:

```
Sql = "update budgetreport" +
                " set sales="+salesText.getText()+
                " where quarter="+ qTracker+
                " set cogs="+cogsText.getText()+
                " where quarter="+ qTracker;
        try {
            myStmt.executeUpdate(Sql);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

My problem is, it says there is an SQL syntax. I ran it with just the first part:

```
Sql = "update budgetreport" +
                " set sales="+salesText.getText()+
                " where quarter="+ qTracker;
        try {
            myStmt.executeUpdate(Sql);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And it ran fine. But I do not under stand what to do in order to make my first snippet of code function. Thanks for taking your time to read/answer :)!
......

Comment: I don't know much about MySql, but it seems as if it should be two different `update` statements: one for `sales` and one for `cogs`.

Comment: Also you want to use preparedStatements, as building SQL this way will lead you eventually down a dark path

Comment: If your question is resolved, please mark one of the answers as accepted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only one SET keyword is allowed per update

```
String sql = "update budgetreport" +
                " set sales=?, cogs=?" + 
                " where quarter=?";

PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
preparedStatement.setString(1, salesText.getText());
...
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: How does the  "PreparedStament" object help? Just curious, thanks!

Comment: It protects against [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks as well takes care of quoting of character types

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that. I'll be sure to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sql = "update budgetreport" +
      " set sales="+salesText.getText()+
      ", cogs="+cogsText.getText()+
      " where quarter="+ qTracker;
```

Watch out for SQL injection attacks and errors, you shouldn't be concatenating with unchecked textbox contents.

Comment: Gee I really feel like an idiot now. All I was missing was a comma!

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the response, I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a [prepared statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). It's far safer.

```
String sql = "update budgetreport set sales=? where quarter=?";

PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(sql);

statement.setString(1, salesText.getText());
statement.setString(2, qTracker.toString());

statement.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score -1):

You should probably start here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp since your SQL syntax is incorrect. Try

```
update budgetreport set sales=?,cogs=? where quarter=?
```

The above should be a prepared statement. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Or, you could ease your life a bit by using some light-weight frameworks like this: http://www.sql2o.org/ which abstracts PreparedStatements and makes your code more readable.

Answer (score -1):

The syntax for the update query is incorrect so you need to change it>

UPDATE table

SET column1 = expression1,

```
column2 = expression2,
....
```

WHERE conditions;

for example

Sql =`update budgetreport" +
      " set sales="+salesText.getText()+
      ", cogs="+cogsText.getText()+
      " where quarter="+ qTracker;"`